# Invoking an injected Scala class from an Akka actor

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka, guice

I have the following class in Play for Scala that injects another class:

```
class MainEtl2 @Inject() (ic: injectedClass) {
    def run (option: String) = {
      ic.method1() 
      // ... some code
    }
}
```

I need to call the method `run` in an Akka Actor. This is my attempt, assuming that Guice will inject `injectedClass` when `MainEtl2` is invoked:

```
class MainEtl extends Actor {

  @Inject val me2 : MainEtl2

  def receive = {
    case option: String => {         
        val x = me2.run(option)
        // ... more code
        }
     } 
  }
```

`MainEtl` class does not compile with the followint error:

```
class MainEtl needs to be abstract, since value me2 is not defined
```

How to make this work?

Comment: Have you tried injecting `me2` in the constructor for `MainEtl` ?

Comment: yes, see my comment to the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would propose such solution based on [Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAkka#Dependency-injecting-actors). Define your actor in such way:

```
class MainEtl @Inject() (me2: MainEtl2) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case option: String => {         
      val x = me2.run(option)
    }
  } 
}
```

Define play module with Akka support and bind named actor:

```
class AkkaBindings extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
  bindActor[MainEtl]("mainEtl")
}
```

Register this module in application.conf by adding

```
play.modules.enabled += "some.package.AkkaBindings"
```

Now you can inject your actor by name reference:

```
class Scheduler @Inject()(@Named("mainEtl") mainEtl: ActorRef) {
  //some code
  val scheduler = QuartzSchedulerExtension(system)
  scheduler.schedule("dailyproc", mainEtl, "abc", None)
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this worked. The only caveat is that you need to defined a configure method if you extend `AbstractModule` as explained [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#programmatic-bindings)

Answer (score 1):

I would try inject `MainEtl2` similar to how `CountingService` is injected in [this example](http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/activator-akka-scala-guice#code/src/main/scala/sample/CountingActor.scala):

```
class MainEtl @Inject() (me2: MainEtl2) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case option: String => {         
      val x = me2.run(option)
      // ... more code
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: I injected MainEtl2 in MainEtl, but I get an error when I try to instantiate the actor: `val actor = system.actorOf(Props[MainEtl])` throws: `Error injecting constructor, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no matching constructor found on class MainEtl for arguments []`

Comment: Did you follow how the said sample app configures `CountingActor` using [scala-guice](https://github.com/rocketraman/activator-akka-scala-guice/blob/master/src/main/scala/sample/SampleModule.scala) and instantiates the actor from its `Main` app?  It has been a while since I tested the sample app from Lightbend but it did work as advertised.

Comment: I tried to follow this project but it's too complex, all I'm looking for is to send a message to an actor that has an injected object, I guess there's no simple way to do this.

Comment: Yes, the sample app injects a service (CountingService) as well as an actor (AuditBus) into CountingActor.  But if you discard the Audit-related code, you should be able to adapt the remaining skeleton by substituting CountingService (which also injects a Config class) with MainEtl2 and CountingActor with MainEtl.

Answer (score 0):

Though you are specifying @Inject annotation, you still need an initial value which guice will override while injecting dependencies, so try this,

```
class MainEtl extends Actor {

  @Inject val me2 : MainEtl2 = null //initial value.

  def receive = {
    case option: String => {         
        val x = me2.run(option)
        // ... more code
        }
     } 
  }
```

Comment: This didn't work, `me2` is null and cannot run the method. This is the error I get: `[error] a.a.OneForOneStrategy - null
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at tasks.etl.MainEtl$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(MainEtl.scala:17)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:484)`

Comment: How you are creating instance of MainEtl? It should be created through Guice, if you have created it with new, the injection will not work in that class.

Comment: MainEtl starts fine, the problem is when `me2.run` is invoked. I use `akka-quartz-scheduler` to start MainEtl: `val scheduler = QuartzSchedulerExtension(system)` `val receiver = system.actorOf(Props[MainEtl])` `scheduler.schedule("dailyproc", receiver, "abc", None)`

Comment: When I debug the line `val x = me2.run(option)`, me2 is null. But the MainEtl actor is initiated with no issues

Comment: Your injection was not working as MainEtl was not created through injection, the injection in MainEtl will only work if you instantiate MainEtl itself through injection.